# DOMElement getElementsByTagName() doesn't work

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Why am I not getting anything when I echo the results in this code:

```
$result1 = '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&amp;">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result1);
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('HEAD');
echo $items->item(0); // error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the lowercase tag names:

```
$result1 = '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&amp;">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result1);
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head');
                                     ^^^
```

Sidenote: Always turn on error reporting for useful information:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You cannot echo outright since this returns DOM classes.

To loop over head children:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($items->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    print_r($child); // most likely this will show you the child `<title>` node
}
```

Comment: Thanks :). also, i have error_reporting on, it doesn't let you know that you used upper case instead of lower case... thanks again!